# SimpleSC::StopService, SimpleSC::StartService giving infinite timeout

Tags: winapi, windows-services, timeout, nsis

How to give infinite timeout in `SimpleSC::StartService` or `SimpleSC::StopService` or any method of [simple service plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin)?

Comment: You want to wait forever the start of a service? Sounds a bad idea and the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx) seems not being able to do that.

Comment: Agreed that its bad idea.(Asking out of curosity)whats the default timeout if I dont't specify any.

Comment: There is no default. If you don't provide a value, it crashes at runtime. In the examples, it uses a 30 seconds wait period. If you need actually a long wait time, try to provide something like 86400 for a 24h wait time.